# Check if two single linked lists contain the same data

Tags: c++, linked-list, compare

We have to check if two given linked lists contain the same data. Order in this case does not matter, meaning that `{1,3,2}` and `{2,1,3}`are same. I think that we should introduce a new variable `counter=0` and perform the following procedure:

```
while(node1->next!=NULL)
{
    int value=node1->value;
    if(contains(node2,value)){
        counter++;
    }

    node1=node1->next;

    if(counter== number of elements in node 1) 
        return true; 
    else return false;
}
```

Another method is to sort both lists and compare node by node. Which one is optimal? In the first case it takes O(n^2) operations, while in the second case like Nlog(N)+O(N), (if we use merge sort). Am I right in my thinking? Or is there another optimal method?

Comment: The real answer is: if you have to do that, don't use a linked list in the first place!

Comment: Do you have a constraint on memory complexity?-If not it is possible to imlement it in O(n) memory and O(m+n) time,when n and m are lengths of the lists.It is possible by using hashmap or or kind of bitmap

Comment: how about using a hashmap? i am sceptical about duplicate elements though.

Comment: @ Jerry Coffin i see,just it is question from programming book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the two methods you posted, 2nd is better. But I would suggest you to `hashing`.

Hash the 1st linked list first.

Check the 2nd list while hashing it.

This way, it can be done in O(n) time in total.

Comment: i like your ans, there needs to be a slight overhead for the duplicates though?

Comment: Wouldn't that give a false positive if the 2nd list was a subset of the first?

Comment: Essentially, the collision in hashing is what is the 'counter' in OP's. So there's little overheards.

Comment: that's another edge case too, hashmap with key as element value as the count of appearances?

Comment: @James, that can be easily figure out using a counters while hashing.  @Morpheus, the counters is can help with duplicates. Because, the final output of the comparison is simply a `true` or `false`

Answer (score 2):

If the values in the linked list allow it, you could create a histogram using the values of the first link and then iterate through the second list decrementing the histogram entries as you go. If at the end the histogram contains only zeroes then they're the same.

So for example if the list1 contains {1, 3, 4, 2, 4} the histogram would be (zero based) [0, 1, 1, 1, 2].

Then if list2 contains {1, 3, 2, 4}, after decrementing the histogram would be [0, 0, 0, 0, 1].

The running time would be O(m + n)

Comment: so for histogram i should introduce another space yes?for example bit array or bit vector

Comment: you can't use a bit array unless you're sure there are no duplicates in either list

Answer (score 1):

This solution takes same time complexity, but still it's a little better!

```
{
 while(node1->next != NULL)
 {
    if(!contains(node2, node1->value)){
        return false;
    }
    node1 = node1->next;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could print the numbers out to a string and then sort the string so everything is in the right order

edit: that's just a suggestion your other ways are better

Answer (score 0):

Here is recursive solution that will definitely work....

```
int CompareLists(Node *headA, Node* headB)
{

if (headA == NULL && headB == NULL)     
{  return 1;  }
if (headA == NULL && headB != NULL)  
{  return 0;  }
if (headB != NULL && headB == NULL)  
{  return 0;  }
if (headA->data != headB->data)
{  return 0;  }

return CompareLists(headA->next, headB->next);  
}
```